# Remove a line if all fields match a specific pattern

Tags: bash, awk

If I want to remove a line with a specific pattern in one field, for example the third field, I could write:

```
awk '$3!='pattern' file
```

If I want to remove lines in which all fields match a specific pattern, how could I do that? Here is an example file:

```
number1 1245 1/2 1/2 1/2 1/2
number2 1468 1/1 1/2 2/2 1/2
```

I want to remove the first line in this case as all fields after the second field contain `1/2` with no exception.

Thanks.

Comment: Could use sed `sed '/^\(1\/2[[:space:]]*\)\+$/d'`

Comment: Thanks. It works. I had to change my original file structure in the question as in my actual file, I have several columns before the ones that can have the pattern. Anyway, I will make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using sed

```
sed '\`^\([^[:space:]]\+[[:space:]]\+\)\{2\}\(1/2[[:space:]]\+\)\+1/2[[:space:]]*$`d' file
```

with `-r/-E` flag

```
sed -r '\`^([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){2}(1/2[[:space:]]+)+1/2[[:space:]]*$`d' file
```

Assuming only spaces are used  and not other whitespace characters.

```
sed -r '\`^([^ ]+ +){2}(1/2 +)+1/2 *$`d' file
```

---

Using awk

```
awk '{for(i=3;i<=NF;i++)if($i!="1/2")next;print}' file
```

Prints

```
number2 1468 1/1 1/2 2/2 1/2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `sed` for simple line-oriented editing like this:

```
$ sed '/pattern/d' input
```

In this case, you want to remove all line that has four consecutive occurrences of "`<space>1/2`" at the end of the line:

```
$ sed '/\( 1\/2\)\{4\}$/d' input
```

Alternatively,

```
$ sed -E '/( 1\/2){4}$/d' input
```

(if you have GNU `sed`, use `-r` instead of `-E`. I'm on a BSD system and use BSD `sed`)

**UPDATE**: Thanks to @EdMorton for commenting that you may get rid of the somewhat ugly `\/` in the pattern in the following way:

```
$ sed '\:\( 1/2\)\{4\}$:d' input
```

or

```
$ sed -E '\:( 1/2){4}$:d' input
```

That may not matter much in this case, but sure makes the whole thing a lot easier to read in more complicated `sed` editing scripts.

Comment: except without anchors it only has to contains 1/2 on the last one, could be 1/24

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the `-E` info. However, it's only the `s` command that takes alternative delimiters.  `sed ':pattern:d'` will unfortunately not wok.

Comment: @EdMorton Ah! Goodly.

Comment: @EdMorton Maybe the new GNU sed accepts -E but not all versions do.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{delete cnt; for (i=3;i<=NF;i++) cnt[$i]++} cnt["1/2"] < length(cnt)' file
number2 1468 1/1 1/2 2/2 1/2
```